# How to convert part of a list into integers in Python?

Tags: python

I have lists with names and scores in them, for example:

```
[['AMY', '2', '9', '10'], ['ANNA', '10', '4', '7'], ['BOB', '6', '7', '10']]
```

And I want it to end up like this:

```
[['AMY', 2, 9, 10], ['ANNA', 10, 4, 7], ['BOB', 6, 7, 10]]
```

I need to convert the numbers to integers because they're giving me problems when trying to use the max() function because it doesn't recognise 10 as the largest item. I have tried for so long but I keep getting different types of errors. I've searched around and everyone seems to be telling me to use map or list comprehension but none of these seem to work.

Comment: If you convert part of it to integers, `max()` will fail entirely because it'll be trying to compare `int` with `str` and that doesn't work in Python 3.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think you should change your structure to a dictionary, like `data = {'AMY': [2, 9, 10], ...}` and then for each person you can calculate the maximum. Would such a transformation interest you?

Comment: Yes please. May you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

```
data = [['AMY', '2', '9', '10'], ['ANNA', '10', '4', '7'], ['BOB', '6', '7', '10']]
dict_data = {sublist[0]: list(map(int, sublist[1:])) for sublist in data}
```

And now you can access each person's numbers with their name, for example:

```
>>> print(dict_data['AMY'])
[2, 9, 10]
>>> print(max(dict_data['AMY']))
10
```

For the dictionary creation, you use the first element in the sublist as the key and then convert the rest to integers with `map()`. And as you've probably read in other questions `list(map(int, sublist[1:]))` is the same as `[int(i) for i in sublist[1:]]`.

Answer (score 0):

solution is:

```
data = [['AMY', '2', '9', '10'], ['ANNA', '10', '4', '7'], ['BOB', '6', '7', '10']]
print [[a if not a.isdigit() else int(a) for a in element] for element in data]
```

Comment: Maybe because of topic starter dose not exactly know what he want 0_o

Comment: Similar to Apero's answer, your solution has a flaw that TigerhawkT3 mentioned in the comments: mixing strings and integers in a list will cause `max()` to raise an error. Just because in his ignorance the OP asked for exactly what you deliver doesn't exactly make your answer useful. At least not without mentioning that your answer to his demands will result to further problems down the line.

Comment: I'm so sorry! I didn't mean to seem rude or anything. The code that you deleted did work (thank you so much). I was just open to other ways of solving my problem, if there was a more efficient way or anything. Again, thank you for your input.

Comment: No issue, it was correct but yeah TigerhawkT3 solution is more interesting to apply functions like max or sum or whatever needs to work on numbers only

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like the first element of each `list` is a name and the other elements are perhaps test scores, you should use a dictionary with a key of the person's name and a value of a `list` of scores:

```
l = [['AMY', '2', '9', '10'], ['ANNA', '10', '4', '7'], ['BOB', '6', '7', '10']]
dct = {x[0]:[int(el) for el in x[1:]] for x in l}
```

You can then work with the data more easily:

```
>>> for name in dct:
...     print(name, max(dct[name]))
...
('AMY', 10)
('BOB', 10)
('ANNA', 10)
```

Comment: This is a clean alternative solution to the OP's problem.

Answer (score -1):

What you have is a collection of records. That is your `data`.

```
data = [
  ['AMY', '2', '9', '10'],
  ['ANNA', '10', '4', '7'],
  ['BOB', '6', '7', '10']
  ]
```

Your first question is how to transform each record.  The right way to do that is to define a transform and map it across your list of records.  For example, you could do the first thing you ask for like this:

```
def transform_record(lst):
  name = lst[0]
  grades = list(map(int, lst[1:]))
  grades.insert(0, name)
  return grades

print(list(map(transform_record, data)))
```

But maybe that is an unneeded exta step.  The second thing you mention is wanting to associate a maximum score with each name.  So instead of producing a full transform of each record, you can pull out just the information you want.

```
def name_best(lst):
  name = lst[0]
  grades = map(int, lst[1:])
  best = max(grades)
  return (name, best)

print(list(map(name_best, data)))
```